# Add a bought font file to my WebStorm project using SASS. Angular Project

Tags: css, font-face

I want to know what am i missing here?
I have the following definition in my SASS file:

```
@font-face
  font-family: "NHaasGroteskDSPro"
  src: url("fonts/NHaasGroteskDSPro-95Blk.otf") format("otf")

h1.ir-page-header
  font-family: "NHaasGroteskDSPro"
  font-weight: 800
  font-size: 30px
```

And the relevant HTML element is:

```
<h1 class="ir-page-header">some text</h1>
```

The developer tool shows that the element has the required class and its not override by other css styles. 
Sadly the font showed is not the font wanted.

here is a link to the font page on fonts.com:
http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/neue-haas-grotesk/display-family-pack

I thought it will be easy to find the answer online but after spending 2 hours on a 10 min task i decided to post my question for future generations :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i changed the @font-face to be:

```
@font-face
  font-family: "Neue Haas Grotesk"
  font-weight: 800
  font-style: normal
  src: url("fonts/NHaasGroteskDSPro-95Blk.otf") format("opentype")
```

And it solved the problem.

Comment: This saved me!!

Answer (score 0):

Better solution will be using webfonts. You need different font formats to support different browsers and achieve smallest file size. In a case of paid font, please see http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts.

CSS Webfont declaration looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontName';
src: url('/fonts/font-webfont.eot');
src: url('/fonts/font-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/font-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('/fonts/font-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/font-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/font-webfont.svg#FontName') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```